# vague error message when exploring the contents of an S3 bucket

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've created a linked service to S3 which connects without any problems, however when I create a data set and attempt to explore the contents of the bucket, I get the following error message:

The file operation is failed.. Activity ID:dee933af-54f6-4146-87f9-4158d98a09b9

is there anyway I can obtain information that might help be troubleshoot what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

from the backend logs, we can see that the error is complaining about : The remote name could not be resolved: "adf-***.10.***.112.**". Could you double check whether the bucket name is valid, and it can be accessed from your self-hosted IR?

If the bucket name is correct. You can try using Azure IR to do the browse. If it works, it means the failure is caused by a connectivity issue from your self-hosted IR to the S3 account (e.g. firewall setting, proxy)